# Running Bluetooth as background service not working properly

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-service

*I am new in android any help please help me and thanks in advance. 
I want that bluetooth is always connected in app while switching from one activity to another. so I am making background service . There are two classes first class shows the list of paired device and second class is used to run the bluetooth as background service . There is no error Everything is fine but when I switch the activity Bluetooth is disconnected and also it didn't show the status changed. Ask me If you need  any additional information *

This is my first class Homescreen class

```
  public class Homescreen extends Activity {
    public static Homescreen home;
    private Button mBtnSearch;
    private Button mBtnConnect;
    private ListView mLstDevices;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBTAdapter;

    private static final int BT_ENABLE_REQUEST = 10; // This is the code we use for BT Enable
    private static final int SETTINGS = 20;

    private UUID mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // Standard SPP UUID
    // (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)

    private int mBufferSize = 50000; //Default
    public static final String DEVICE_EXTRA = "com.blueserial.SOCKET";
    public static final String DEVICE_UUID = "com.blueserial.uuid";
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST = "com.blueserial.devicelist";
    private static final String DEVICE_LIST_SELECTED = "com.blueserial.devicelistselected";
    public static final String BUFFER_SIZE = "com.blueserial.buffersize";
    private static final String TAG = "BlueTest5-Homescreen";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
        home=this;
        ActivityHelper.initialize(this); //This is to ensure that the rotation persists across activities and not just this one
        Log.d(TAG, "Created");

        mBtnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        mBtnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);

        mLstDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDevices);

        /*
         *Check if there is a savedInstanceState. If yes, that means the onCreate was probably triggered by a configuration change
         *like screen rotate etc. If that's the case then populate all the views that are necessary here 
         */
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(DEVICE_LIST);
            if(list!=null){
                initList(list);
                MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)mLstDevices.getAdapter();
                int selectedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(DEVICE_LIST_SELECTED);
                if(selectedIndex != -1){
                    adapter.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
                    mBtnConnect.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                initList(new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>());
            }

        } else {
            initList(new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>());
        }


        mBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                if (mBTAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBT, BT_ENABLE_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    new SearchDevices().execute();
                }
            }
        });

        mBtnConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intt=new Intent(Homescreen.this,BluetoothService.class);
                //bindService( intt, null, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                BluetoothDevice device = ((MyAdapter) (mLstDevices.getAdapter())).getSelectedItem();
                intt.putExtra(DEVICE_EXTRA, device);
                intt.putExtra(DEVICE_UUID, mDeviceUUID.toString());
                intt.putExtra(BUFFER_SIZE, mBufferSize);
                startService(intt);
//              Toast.makeText(Homescreen.this, "Device Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//              BluetoothDevice device = ((MyAdapter) (mLstDevices.getAdapter())).getSelectedItem();
//              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainBluetooth.class);
//              intent.putExtra(DEVICE_EXTRA, device);
//              intent.putExtra(DEVICE_UUID, mDeviceUUID.toString());
//              intent.putExtra(BUFFER_SIZE, mBufferSize);
//              startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Called when the screen rotates. If this isn't handled, data already generated is no longer available
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) (mLstDevices.getAdapter());
        ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = (ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>) adapter.getEntireList();

        if (list != null) {
            outState.putParcelableArrayList(DEVICE_LIST, list);
            int selectedIndex = adapter.selectedIndex;
            outState.putInt(DEVICE_LIST_SELECTED, selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case BT_ENABLE_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                msg("Bluetooth Enabled successfully");
                new SearchDevices().execute();
            } else {
                msg("Bluetooth couldn't be enabled");
            }

            break;
        case SETTINGS: //If the settings have been updated
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String uuid = prefs.getString("prefUuid", "Null");
            mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(uuid);
            Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + uuid);
            String bufSize = prefs.getString("prefTextBuffer", "Null");
            mBufferSize = Integer.parseInt(bufSize);

            String orientation = prefs.getString("prefOrientation", "Null");
            Log.d(TAG, "Orientation: " + orientation);
            if (orientation.equals("Landscape")) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else if (orientation.equals("Portrait")) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            } else if (orientation.equals("Auto")) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Quick way to call the Toast
     * @param str
     */
    private void msg(String str) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the List adapter
     * @param objects
     */
    private void initList(List<BluetoothDevice> objects) {
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.lstContent, objects);
        mLstDevices.setAdapter(adapter);
        mLstDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
                mBtnConnect.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Searches for paired devices. Doesn't do a scan! Only devices which are paired through Settings->Bluetooth
     * will show up with this. I didn't see any need to re-build the wheel over here
     * @author ryder
     *
     */
    private class SearchDevices extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<BluetoothDevice>> {

        @Override
        protected List<BluetoothDevice> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            List<BluetoothDevice> listDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                listDevices.add(device);
            }
            return listDevices;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<BluetoothDevice> listDevices) {
            super.onPostExecute(listDevices);
            if (listDevices.size() > 0) {
                MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter) mLstDevices.getAdapter();
                adapter.replaceItems(listDevices);
            } else {
                msg("No paired devices found, please pair your serial BT device and try again");
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Custom adapter to show the current devices in the list. This is a bit of an overkill for this 
     * project, but I figured it would be good learning
     * Most of the code is lifted from somewhere but I can't find the link anymore
     * @author ryder
     *
     */
    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {
        private int selectedIndex;
        private Context context;
        private int selectedColor = Color.parseColor("#abcdef");
        private List<BluetoothDevice> myList;

        public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<BluetoothDevice> objects) {
            super(ctx, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            context = ctx;
            myList = objects;
            selectedIndex = -1;
        }

        public void setSelectedIndex(int position) {
            selectedIndex = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getSelectedItem() {
            return myList.get(selectedIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return myList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public BluetoothDevice getItem(int position) {
            return myList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv;
        }

        public void replaceItems(List<BluetoothDevice> list) {
            myList = list;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public List<BluetoothDevice> getEntireList() {
            return myList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lstContent);

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

            if (selectedIndex != -1 && position == selectedIndex) {
                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
            } else {
                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            BluetoothDevice device = myList.get(position);
            holder.tv.setText(device.getName() + "\n   " + device.getAddress());

            return vi;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homescreen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Homescreen.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SETTINGS);
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my second class BluetoothService Class

```
    public class BluetoothService extends Service {
        public static BluetoothService service;

        private boolean mConnectSuccessful = true;
        private static boolean isRunning = false;
        private static final String TAG = "BlueTest5-MainActivity";
        private int mMaxChars = 50000;//Default
        //private UUID mDeviceUUID=UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        private UUID mDeviceUUID;

        private BluetoothSocket mBTSocket;
        private boolean mIsBluetoothConnected = false;

        //private BluetoothDevice mDevice=Homescreen.home.device;
        private BluetoothDevice mDevice;

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Intent intt = getIntent();
//          Bundle b = intt.getExtras();
//          mDevice = b.getParcelable(Homescreen.DEVICE_EXTRA);
//          mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(Homescreen.DEVICE_UUID));
//          mMaxChars = b.getInt(Homescreen.BUFFER_SIZE);
//          super.onStart(intent, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            service=this;
              IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
                IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
                IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
                this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
                this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
                this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          Intent intent = getIntent();
//          Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
//          mDevice = b.getParcelable(Homescreen.DEVICE_EXTRA);
//          mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(Homescreen.DEVICE_UUID));
//          mMaxChars = b.getInt(Homescreen.BUFFER_SIZE);


            super.onCreate();
        }

         @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

       @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            mDevice = b.getParcelable(Homescreen.DEVICE_EXTRA);
            mDeviceUUID = UUID.fromString(b.getString(Homescreen.DEVICE_UUID));
            mMaxChars = b.getInt(Homescreen.BUFFER_SIZE);
            Log.i("mDeviceUUID", ""+mDeviceUUID);
            Log.d("mDevice",""+mDevice );
           new ConnectBT().execute();
           return START_STICKY;
           //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


       public boolean isRunning() {
            return isRunning;
        }

       @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           // Unregister broadcast listeners
            this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
        class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            //ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130220/1287554
            // progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BluetoothService.this, "Hold on", "Connecting");
                Log.d("check check check", "check1");
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) {
                Log.d("check check check", "check2");
                try {
                    Log.e("check check check", "check3");
                    if (mBTSocket == null || !mIsBluetoothConnected) {
                        Log.e("UUID", ""+mDeviceUUID);
                        Log.e("mDevice", ""+mDevice);
                        mBTSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mDeviceUUID);
                        Log.d("check check check", "check4");
                        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                        mBTSocket.connect();
                        Log.d("check check check", "check5");
                    //  Toast.makeText(BluetoothService.this, "background service start", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Unable to connect to device
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mConnectSuccessful = false;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if (!mConnectSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(BluetoothService.this, "Could not connect to device. Is it a Serial device? Also check if the UUID is correct in the settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Device Status in service", "Disconnected");



                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(BluetoothService.this, "Connected to device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Device Status in service", "Device Connected");
                    mIsBluetoothConnected = true;
                     // Kick off input reader
                }
                //progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }


          //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //Do something if connected
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Bluetooth device connected","BT Connected");
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                //Do something if disconnected
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Bluetooth device disconnected","BT Disconnected");
            }
            //else if...
        }
    };


    }
```

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395970/android-bluetooth-background-listner

Answer (score 0):

Android's AsyncTask class will help you. Do the bluetooth discovery task in the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask.You can Toast a message a after the task in the onPostExecute() method. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) is sample code snippet to demonstrate the use of AsyncTask

Comment: As I am new in android can you please elaborate